# Writing Nested JSON Dictionary List To CSV

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv

### Issue

I'm trying to write the following nested list of dictionary which has another list of dictionary to csv. I tried multiple ways but I can not get it to properly write it:

### Json Data

```
[
    {
        "Basic_Information_Source": [
            {
                "Image": "image1.png",
                "Image_Format": "PNG",
                "Image_Mode": "RGB",
                "Image_Width": 574,
                "Image_Height": 262,
                "Image_Size": 277274
            }
        ],
        "Basic_Information_Destination": [
            {
                "Image": "image1_dst.png",
                "Image_Format": "PNG",
                "Image_Mode": "RGB",
                "Image_Width": 574,
                "Image_Height": 262,
                "Image_Size": 277539
            }
        ],
        "Values": [
            {
                "Value1": 75.05045463635267,
                "Value2": 0.006097560975609756,
                "Value3": 0.045083481733371615,
                "Value4": 0.008639858263904898
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Basic_Information_Source": [
            {
                "Image": "image2.png",
                "Image_Format": "PNG",
                "Image_Mode": "RGB",
                "Image_Width": 1600,
                "Image_Height": 1066,
                "Image_Size": 1786254
            }
        ],
        "Basic_Information_Destination": [
            {
                "Image": "image2_dst.png",
                "Image_Format": "PNG",
                "Image_Mode": "RGB",
                "Image_Width": 1600,
                "Image_Height": 1066,
                "Image_Size": 1782197
            }
        ],
        "Values": [
            {
                "Value1": 85.52662890580055,
                "Value2": 0.0005464352720450282,
                "Value3": 0.013496113910369758,
                "Value4": 0.003800236380811839
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

### Working Code

I tried to use the following code and it works, but it only saved the headers and then dumps all the underlying list as text in the csv file:

```
import json
import csv

def Convert_CSV():

    ar_enc_file = open('analysis_results_enc.json','r')
    json_data = json.load(ar_enc_file)

    keys = json_data[0].keys()
    
    with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='')  as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(json_data)

    ar_enc_file.close()

Convert_CSV()
```

### Working Output / Issue with it

The output writes the following header:

- Basic_Information_Source
- Basic_Information_Destination
- Values

And then it dumps all other data inside each header as a list like this:

```
[{'Image': 'image1.png', 'Image_Format': 'PNG', 'Image_Mode': 'RGB', 'Image_Width': 574, 'Image_Height': 262, 'Image_Size': 277274}]
```

### Expected Output / Sample

[image: Expected Output]

Trying to generate the above type of output for each dictionary in the array of dictionaries.

How do it properly write it?

Comment: What is your preferred output?

Comment: Did you want to completely flatten the output? If so, how do you want to represent the nested lists?  We really need to see the output you hope for in order to help.

Comment: @Axe319 Thanks, I've added the expected output format. I'm trying to generate like format for each dict in the array.

Comment: @JonSG Thanks, I've added the expected output format. I'm trying to generate like format for each dict in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone will come by with a much more elegant solution. That being said:

You have a few problems.

- You have inconsistent entries with the fields you want to align.
- Even if you pad your data you have intermediate `list`s that need flattened out.
- Then you still have separated data that needs to be merged together.
- `DictWriter` AFAIK expects it's data in the format of `[{'column': 'entry'},{'column': 'entry'}` so even if you do all the previous steps you're still not in the right format.

So let's get started.

For the first two parts we can combine.

```
def pad_list(lst, size, padding=None):
    # we wouldn't have to make a copy but I prefer to
    # avoid the possibility of getting bitten by mutability
    _lst = lst[:]
    for _ in range(len(lst), size):
        _lst.append(padding)
    return _lst


# this expects already parsed json data
def flatten(json_data):
    lst = []
    for dct in json_data:
        # here we're just setting a max size of all dict entries
        # this is in case the shorter entry is in the first iteration
        max_size = 0
        # we initialize a dict for each of the list entries
        # this is in case you have inconsistent lengths between lists
        flattened = dict()
        for k, v in dct.items():
            entries = list(next(iter(v), dict()).values())
            flattened[k] = entries
            max_size = max(len(entries), max_size)
        # here we append the padded version of the keys for the dict
        lst.append({k: pad_list(v, max_size) for k, v in flattened.items()})
    return lst
```

So now we have a flattened, list of `dict`s whos values are `list`s of consistent length. Essentially:

```
[
    {
        "Basic_Information_Source": [
            "image1.png",
            "PNG",
            "RGB",
            574,
            262,
            277274
        ],
        "Basic_Information_Destination": [
            "image1_dst.png",
            "PNG",
            "RGB",
            574,
            262,
            277539
        ],
        "Values": [
            75.05045463635267,
            0.006097560975609756,
            0.045083481733371615,
            0.008639858263904898,
            None,
            None
        ]
    }
]
```

But this `list` has multiple `dict`s that need to be merged, not just one.

So we need to merge.

```
# this should be self explanatory
def merge(flattened):
    merged = dict()
    for dct in flattened:
        for k, v in dct.items():
            if k not in merged:
                merged[k] = []
            merged[k].extend(v)
    return merged
```

This gives us something close to this:

```
{
    "Basic_Information_Source": [
        "image1.png",
        "PNG",
        "RGB",
        574,
        262,
        277274,
        "image2.png",
        "PNG",
        "RGB",
        1600,
        1066,
        1786254
    ],
    "Basic_Information_Destination": [
        "image1_dst.png",
        "PNG",
        "RGB",
        574,
        262,
        277539,
        "image2_dst.png",
        "PNG",
        "RGB",
        1600,
        1066,
        1782197
    ],
    "Values": [
        75.05045463635267,
        0.006097560975609756,
        0.045083481733371615,
        0.008639858263904898,
        None,
        None,
        85.52662890580055,
        0.0005464352720450282,
        0.013496113910369758,
        0.003800236380811839,
        None,
        None
    ]
}
```

But wait, we still need to format it for the writer.

Our data needs to be in the format of `[{'column_1': 'entry', column_2: 'entry'},{'column_1': 'entry', column_2: 'entry'}`

So we format:

```
def format_for_writer(merged):
    formatted = []
    for k, v in merged.items():
        for i, item in enumerate(v):
            # on the first pass this will append an empty dict
            # on subsequent passes it will be ignored
            # and add keys into the existing dict
            if i >= len(formatted):
                formatted.append(dict())
            formatted[i][k] = item
    return formatted
```

So finally, we have a nice clean formatted data structure we can just hand to our writer function.

```
def convert_csv(formatted):
    keys = formatted[0].keys()
    with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='')  as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(formatted)
```

Full code with `json` string:

```
import json
import csv

json_raw = """\
[
    {
        "Basic_Information_Source": [
            {
                "Image": "image1.png",
                "Image_Format": "PNG",
                "Image_Mode": "RGB",
                "Image_Width": 574,
                "Image_Height": 262,
                "Image_Size": 277274
            }
        ],
        "Basic_Information_Destination": [
            {
                "Image": "image1_dst.png",
                "Image_Format": "PNG",
                "Image_Mode": "RGB",
                "Image_Width": 574,
                "Image_Height": 262,
                "Image_Size": 277539
            }
        ],
        "Values": [
            {
                "Value1": 75.05045463635267,
                "Value2": 0.006097560975609756,
                "Value3": 0.045083481733371615,
                "Value4": 0.008639858263904898
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Basic_Information_Source": [
            {
                "Image": "image2.png",
                "Image_Format": "PNG",
                "Image_Mode": "RGB",
                "Image_Width": 1600,
                "Image_Height": 1066,
                "Image_Size": 1786254
            }
        ],
        "Basic_Information_Destination": [
            {
                "Image": "image2_dst.png",
                "Image_Format": "PNG",
                "Image_Mode": "RGB",
                "Image_Width": 1600,
                "Image_Height": 1066,
                "Image_Size": 1782197
            }
        ],
        "Values": [
            {
                "Value1": 85.52662890580055,
                "Value2": 0.0005464352720450282,
                "Value3": 0.013496113910369758,
                "Value4": 0.003800236380811839
            }
        ]
    }
]
"""


def pad_list(lst, size, padding=None):
    _lst = lst[:]
    for _ in range(len(lst), size):
        _lst.append(padding)
    return _lst


def flatten(json_data):
    lst = []
    for dct in json_data:
        max_size = 0
        flattened = dict()
        for k, v in dct.items():
            entries = list(next(iter(v), dict()).values())
            flattened[k] = entries
            max_size = max(len(entries), max_size)
        lst.append({k: pad_list(v, max_size) for k, v in flattened.items()})
    return lst


def merge(flattened):
    merged = dict()
    for dct in flattened:
        for k, v in dct.items():
            if k not in merged:
                merged[k] = []
            merged[k].extend(v)
    return merged


def format_for_writer(merged):
    formatted = []
    for k, v in merged.items():
        for i, item in enumerate(v):
            if i >= len(formatted):
                formatted.append(dict())
            formatted[i][k] = item
    return formatted


def convert_csv(formatted):
    keys = formatted[0].keys()
    with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='')  as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(formatted)


def main():
    json_data = json.loads(json_raw)
    flattened = flatten(json_data)
    merged = merge(flattened)
    formatted = format_for_writer(merged)
    convert_csv(formatted)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```